# Are groups completely determined by their representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Recently, I became interested in representation theory, and I found out a natural philosophical (vague) question:  are groups completely determined by their representations?

To be specific, I want to know answers about following questions:

(1) For any (discrete) group $G$ and a field $k$, let $\text{Rep}_{G,k}$ be the category of representations of $G$ over $k$. If $\text{Rep}_{G,k}$ and $\text{Rep}_{G',k}$ are equivalent for all $k$, does this implies $G\simeq G'$? How about finite dimensional representation?

(2) What happens if '(discrete) group' changed to other kinds of groups (and representation also changed by appropriate alternatives), such as continuous representations of topological groups, or smooth representations of Lie groups?

Since (1) and (2) are just my formulations of the original question, please let me know if there exist other better-formulated specific questions related to the original question. Also, if you know related theorems (or conjectures), even if they do not exactly focus on (1) and (2), please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/500/finite-groups-with-the-same-character-table

Comment: (complex) Representations are completely determined by characters, but according to the link, the same character table does not necessarily mean the equivalent category of representations... interesting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the Annals paper "A Counterexample to the Isomorphism Problem for Integral Group Rings" by Martin Hertweck. He constructs two finite groups $G$, $H$ such that the integral group rings $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $\mathbb{Z}H$ are isomorphic as rings.  In particular this means that $Rep_{G,R}$ and $Rep_{H,R}$ equivalent as categories for any base ring $R$.

Of course categories of representations of groups come equipped with additional structure (i.e. a symmetric monoidal structure), and these equivalences will not preserve those structures.

Comment: If the rings are isomorphic, then I would expect that the categories of representations should also be equivalent as symmetric monoidal categories.

Comment: @CaptainLama These are noncommutative rings. The tensor product comes from a Hopf algebra structure, which I'm sure isn't preserved by Hertweck's isomorphisms.

Comment: @Nate I'm not sure why you call the tensor product an "addition" structure. That sounds like you're talking about the biproduct.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I see, good remark for the tensor product. I think Nate meant "additional structure".

Comment: Indeed it was supposed to read additional.  The symmetric monoidal structure I was referring to is tensor products which indeed comes from the Hopf ring structures on $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $\mathbb{Z}H$. In particular the group rings Hertwick constructs are isomorphic as rings, but not as Hopf rings. Correspondingly, the categories of representations are equivalent as abelian categories, but not as symmetric monoidal categories.

Comment: This is an extremely fascinating counterexample! Thanks a lot. By the way, do you know any theorem (or conjecture) dealing with some affirmative results, such as "If G is some special category of groups and category of representations has blah blah structure, then the category of representations of G completely determine G "?

Comment: Try looking up Tannakian formalism or Tannaka-Krein duality.

Comment: This is what I want. Wonderful. Thanks a lot!