# Same group ring implies same group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, group-rings

is there any example, s.t. $K=\mathbb{C}$ is a field and we have two non-isomoprhic finite groups $G$ and $H$, s.t. the group ring $K[G]$ is isomorphic to $K[H]$ as a $K$-algebra?

The idea of this question is that if I give you the group ring $K[G]$, can you determine the group $G$?

Here [Are groups completely determined by their representations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209980/are-groups-completely-determined-by-their-representations) you can see that there exists an example for the case $K=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The answer you link to provides an example that works for any field (by extending scalars).

Comment: The additional structure you want to consider on the group algebra is the comultiplication which makes it a Hopf algebra. The group is then determined as the set of group-like elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maschke's theorem together with the Artin-Wedderburn theorem tells you that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is isomorphic to a product of matrix algebras $M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ where $d_i$ are the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $G$. So two group algebras of finite groups over $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic iff the dimensions of their complex irreducible representations are the same.

In particular this is true for any two finite abelian groups of the same cardinality, so the smallest example is $G = C_2 \times C_2, H = C_4$ (this is the smallest example of a pair of non-isomorphic groups of the same order). The smallest nonabelian example is $G = Q_8, H = D_4$, whose representations have dimensions $1, 1, 1, 1, 2$ (and which even famously have the same character table).